# Clustering sparse vectors with fixed and continuos components

Tags: k-means, sparse-matrix

Please advice on encoding data for the following clustering problem. 
I have a dataset with car usage info. Dataset has the following fields:
1. Car model  (Toyoya Celica, BMW, Nissan X-Trail, Mazda Cosmo, etc.)
2. Year built 
3. Country where the car runs 
4. Distance run by car before major repairs

Important: The above dataset is sparse. 
In most cases "Distance" is not known for all countries for a given car.

Problem: 
For a given car predict the "Distance" it will run before major repairs in a country for which "Distance" is unknown.

My approach:
I want to represent each record in the dataset as a sparse vector with the following components:
1. Binary (1/0) car model components. Number of these components equals the number of all possible models in the dataset.
2. Binary (1/0) country where the car runs. Number of these components equals the number of all possible countries in the dataset.
3. Distance. A single integer component, equals the distance run by car.

Next I want to cluster (k-means) these vectors and analyze resulting groups.

Questions:
1) In my vectors I mix components of different nature - binary (model, country)  and continuous (distance). How to calculate component-wise distance between vectors? Cosine similarity?
2) Other ways to encode components with finite set of values (model, country) to work well with continuous components (such as distance)?

Thanks!
Anton

Answer (score 1):

1) From my experience, the norm is just to weight the features (of the entire dataset) such that their ranges are similar. I don't think cosine similarity would work quite as well - consider 2 cars that have a distance of 1 and 2 km's/miles respectively. Their distances and the difference in their distances are negligible, but it would be significant for cosine similarity (if I understand it correctly).

2) Since a car can only have 1 model and 1 country (I assume), each can just be represented by an integer (0 = Toyota Celica, 1 = BMW, 2 = Nissan X-Trail, 3 = Mazda Cosmo, etc.).

I assume you know nothing about the relation between different models or countries, so just defining the distance as equality (1 if equal, 0 if not, weighted appropriately) would be the best you can do. If a car can have more than 1 model or country, I'd suggest Hamming distance.

I hope you just accidentally skipped Year Built when describing your approach, this is significant numeric data.

All that being said, I don't think clustering would work too well unless you add some additional features (containing some continuous (numeric) data), such as make (Toyota, Nissan, Mazda, etc.), weight, country average temperatures, country average amount of rain or snow, numeric representation of road condition, etc.) if possible. As far as I know, clustering doesn't really work well with non-numeric data (such as make / model), but, if weighted correctly (or if you can define a mathematical relation between different makes / models), I suppose it can work.

Just a thought, but how about defining country by longitude and latitude instead? And then you can calculate the distance between countries. Otherwise I'd probably suggest replacing it by numeric features about the country if possible.

Side note - The problem with using binary fields in clustering (as for equality for makes / models) is that you'll have to pick the weight yourself. This means you'll be leading the clustering, which can mess it up, or at best, cause it to conform to a preconceived notion you have about the data. This is why numeric data is better.